# Последовательное выполнение команд при запуске терминала с опцией execute

Tags: linux, bash

Надо сделать запуск Konsole с параметром, запускающим сразу несколько команд. В их числе и команды `echo` и `read`.

Допустим, пишу:

```
konsole --noclose -e "echo Have fun; echo Have troubles."
```

В этом случае, открывается консоль и выводит:

```
Have fun; echo Have troubles.
```

Несомненно, это не то, что ожидалось. Экранировать пытался, да никак не вышло исправить. `echo` Вне зависимости от наличия кавычек и экранирования "съедает" всю строку.

Как можно это дело обойти?

Вторая проблема заключается в том, что бинарника `read` как такового нет. Чем можно заменить?

Comment: что-то вроде `konsole --noclose -e /bin/sh -c "echo Have fun; echo Have troubles."` ­— взято [отсюда](https://superuser.com/a/998680/734823)

Comment: @diraria Благодарю, это именно то что я искал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно так:

```
konsole --noclose -e /bin/bash -c 'echo "Have fun"; echo "Have troubles."'
```

В документации к [Konsole](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/applications/konsole/command-line-options.html) сказано:

> -e command
>   Execute command instead of the normal shell.
>
> Note
>   This option will catch all following arguments passed to Konsole, and execute it as command. So this option shouldalways be used as the last option.

*Konsole* запустить все последующие аргументы как команду вместо нормальной оболочки - bash, ksh, sh и т.д..
Причем, первым аргументом ожидается выполняемая программа, а все последующие, это ее аргументы.

То есть, указанная в вопросе строка выполнится как:

```
/usr/bin/echo Have fun; echo Have troubles.
```

и ее вывод:

```
Have fun; echo Have troubles.
```

Здесь путь к `echo` может отличаться. Но что важно, это выполняемая команда (*executable*), а не оболочка (*shell*), поэтому ни внутренние команды оболочки (*built-in*, `read` в вопросе), ни ее синтаксические элементы и символы (`;` в вопросе), не имеют здесь своего действия.